# Whats the probability of getting 6 dots on die atleast once after throwing 10 times?

Tags: probability

Whats the probability of getting 6 dots on die atleast once after throwing 10 times?

Most logical way to solve this is to use reverse event, right? :

$A=$Getting $6$ atleast once

$A'=$Not getting $6$ at all

$$\omega=6^{10}$$
$$P(A)=1-P(A')$$
$$P=1- \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{10}$$

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Yep for what it's worth $1-\frac 56^2 \approx 84\%$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

Since probability of getting 6 dots, $\frac16$ and that of not getting 6 dots, $\frac{5}{6}$ both remain constant from one throw to the next. Therefore, you can also use Binomial distribution to find probability of getting $6$ dots on the die, at least once in 10 throws as follows 
$$1-\text{Probability of not getting 6 dots at all in 10 throws}$$
$$=1-^{10}C_0\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^0\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{10}$$

Comment: Could you guide me how the answer would look like if task was modified to:

"What's the avarage number of throws needed to get 6 dots for the first time?" (Not 10 times this time)

My gut is telling me its 3 throws, I don't know how to attack this task with probability logic.

Answer (score 2):

$\checkmark$ That is correct,

There are $6^{10}$ *equally probable* outcomes, and the count for those in the event of "no `6` among ten rolls" is $5^{10}$, and so, by the *rule for probability of complements*, the probability for "at least one `6` among ten rolls" is indeed:$$P=1-\left(\dfrac 5 6\right)^{10}=\dfrac{50700551}{60466176}$$